# How to test catching errors that are thrown outside of the Flutter context?

Tags: flutter, crashlytics

According to Firebase Crashlytics tutorial errors that happen outside of the Flutter context can be caught with

```
Isolate.current.addErrorListener(RawReceivePort((pair) async {
  final List<dynamic> errorAndStacktrace = pair;
  await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(
    errorAndStacktrace.first,
    errorAndStacktrace.last,
    fatal: true,
  );
}).sendPort);
```

[Crashlytics tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=flutter#errors-outside-flutter)

How can I test if these these errors that happen outside of the Flutter context are actually caught? How to invoke such error?

Maybe creating the native channel and invoking the exception might be the answer?